# How do I get all fields for a class in Dart?

Tags: dart, dart-mirrors

I looked at the dart:mirrors library, and I found [ClassMirror](http://api.dartlang.org/docs/releases/latest/dart_mirrors/ClassMirror.html). While I saw `getField` I didn't see access to *all* fields. I did see `getters`, though.

If I want to get all fields for a class, do I have to go through `getters` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Zdeslav Vojkovic's answer is a bit old.

This works for me, for Dart 1.1.3, as of March 2 2014.

```dart
import 'dart:mirrors';

class Test {
    int a = 5;

    static int s = 5;

    final int _b = 6;

    int get b => _b;

    int get c => 0;
}

void main() {

    Test t = new Test();
    InstanceMirror instance_mirror = reflect(t);
    var class_mirror = instance_mirror.type;

    for (var v in class_mirror.declarations.values) {

        var name = MirrorSystem.getName(v.simpleName);

        if (v is VariableMirror) {
            print("Variable: $name => S: ${v.isStatic}, P: ${v.isPrivate}, F: ${v.isFinal}, C: ${v.isConst}");
        } else if (v is MethodMirror) {
            print("Method: $name => S: ${v.isStatic}, P: ${v.isPrivate}, A: ${v.isAbstract}");
        }

    }
}
```

Would output:

```
Variable: a => S: false, P: false, F: false, C: false
Variable: s => S: true, P: false, F: false, C: false
Variable: _b => S: false, P: true, F: true, C: false
Method: b => S: false, P: false, A: false
Method: c => S: false, P: false, A: false
Method: Test => S: false, P: false, A: false
```

Comment: As of today, at least, dart:mirrors is no longer supported for web apps. I get the feeling that it's discouraged for all types of apps.

Answer (score 5):

No, you should go through `ClassMirror.variables`:

```java
class Test {
  int a = 5;
  static int s = 5;
  final int _b = 6;

  int get b => _b;
  int get c => 0;
}

void main() {
  Test t = new Test();
  InstanceMirror instance_mirror = reflect(t);
  var class_mirror = instance_mirror.type;
  for(var v in class_mirror.variables.values)
  {
    var name = MirrorSystem.getName(v.simpleName);
    print("$name => S: ${v.isStatic}, P: ${v.isPrivate}, F: ${v.isFinal}");
  }
}
```

This will output:

```
_b => S: false, P: true, F: true 
a => S: false, P: false, F: false
s => S: true, P: false, F: false
```

`ClassMirror.getters` would only return `b` and `c`.

Comment: Ah ha, thanks! The word `variables` is really misleading, I wish it was called `fields`.

Comment: Agreed: I looked through API docs twice, and missed `variables` both times :) then I noticed `VariableMirror` subclass of `DeclarationMirror`. However, there is also `LibraryMirror`, where variables make more sense, IMO - I guess this is done for consistency (or 'consistency', can't decide :)

Comment: Is this valid? ClassMirror.variables doesn't exist according to the docs

Comment: well, it was in June 2013. I guess that it was replaced with `declarations` property: https://api.dartlang.org/apidocs/channels/stable/#dart-mirrors.ClassMirror@id_declarations

Comment: I have provided with a modified working version, but I am unsure if this is the best solution or if there are better solutions.