# How can I allow a user to choose an Icon for something they're adding?

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to load all the icons from the Icon class and allow the user to pick one of them to be used? For example i want the user to input a text in a textfield and then pick an icon then add that text and icon to some sort of a list. I already know the text part but I can't figure out how to load all the icons and let the user choose one.

Comment: It may be a better idea to have only a limited set of icon that applies to that particular entry. You could enhance by giving it colors of user choice. For example, no need to display a mail icon if the entry is related to a restaurant.

Comment: please give a bit more details about what exactly you want to do.. the Icon class does not contain any icons, you have to pass in an `IconData`. So there is no way to "load all icons from Icon class", as it contains none.

Comment: I have an option for the user to add a "category" of their payments, so to add a new category they provide a text that's the title of the category (Shopping for example) and then i want to let the user choose an icon for that category. Icons.shopping_basket for example. How would i do that?

Comment: Maybe this package might help, I haven't tried it but it has icon picker in it.
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_picker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Flutter Icons are stored as **static class members** and [reflect function](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/server/reflection-with-mirrors) is required to [get a list of members of a class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021327/how-do-i-get-all-fields-for-a-class-in-dart). Dart mirrors are needed to use reflect function and [flutter doesn't allow using dart mirrors](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/1150). So, it seems that it's not possible (or at least easy) to get a list of these members.

See [here](https://github.com/dart-lang/reflectable/issues/117).

I suggest using **material_design_icons_flutter** package with below code.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    List<String> iconListKeys = iconMap.iconMap.keys.toList();
    MdiIcons iconLib = new MdiIcons();
    List<IconData> iconList = iconListKeys
            .map<IconData>((String iconName) => iconLib[iconName])
            .toList();
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text(widget.title),
        ),
        body: Center(
            child: ListView(
                    children: iconList.map<Widget>((icon) => Icon(icon)).toList()),
        ),
    );
}
```

**keep in mind that the mentioned package may become outdated or discontinued. So above solution doesn't seem to be good for general usage.**

Answer (score 0):

Use this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_iconpicker) called as Icon Picker

Example:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_iconpicker/flutter_iconpicker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    const MaterialApp(
      home: HomeScreen(),
    ),
  );
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomeScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeScreenState createState() => _HomeScreenState();
}

class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  Icon? _icon;

  _pickIcon() async {
    IconData? icon = await FlutterIconPicker.showIconPicker(context,
        iconPackModes: [IconPack.cupertino]);

    _icon = Icon(icon);
    setState(() {});

    debugPrint('Picked Icon:  $icon');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: _pickIcon,
              child: const Text('Open IconPicker'),
            ),
            const SizedBox(height: 10),
            AnimatedSwitcher(
              duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 300),
              child: _icon ?? Container(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```