# how to programmatically get the number of properties of a class in dart?

Tags: dart

let say I have a class like this

```
class Human {

   String name;
   int age;
   HairColor hairColor;

   static const int numberOfLegs = 2

}
```

as you can see I have 3 properties and 1 static property in `Human` class above, I want to get the number of class properties (without the static) of a class

so I need to get something like this

```
final john = Human(name: "John", age: 24, hairColor: HairColor.black)
print(john.length) // will print '3'
```

I need to programmatically get the number of properties of a class because I will use it in unit testing, because I create a method to convert that class to map, but If I add a new property, I often forget to add it to the method

```
Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {

   return {
      "name" : this.name,
      "age" : this.age
      "hairColor" : this.hairColor
      "newProperty" : "I often forget to add this new property in this method"
   }

}
```

I see an article to do something like this [in here](https://www.woolha.com/tutorials/dart-getting-list-of-fields-and-methods-in-a-class) and also from SO in [How do I get all fields for a class in Dart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021327/how-do-i-get-all-fields-for-a-class-in-dart) , both of them using `dart:mirrors` , but it seems `dart:mirrors` is no longer available

Comment: "because I create a method to convert that class to map" - **don't do that**: writing entity-to-DTO mapping by-hand is error-prone and _tedious_ (and as a software-dev, your job is to _eliminate tedium!_), so here's a better idea: use `automap` instead: https://pub.dev/packages/automap

Comment: This isn't possible without reflection.  Possibly [`package:reflectable`](https://pub.dev/packages/reflectable) can do it, but I'm not familiar with it.  But if you're serializing to/from JSON, you really should be using code-generation instead (e.g. [`package:json_serializable`](https://pub.dev/packages/json_serializable), [`package:built_value`](https://pub.dev/packages/built_value)).