# How to avoid typing incorrect serialization name when updating a property from a database?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart

I'm using Firestore database and i want to update some fields from a document.

```
var updateFields = {
  "completedByUid": authRepo.getUID(),
  "completed": currentTime,
};

return await docRef.update(updateFields);
```

Instead of typing the properyName manually how can i get the name directly from an object Object, and by this avoiding typing it incorrectly or outdated.

Let's say i have an object like:

```
@JsonSerializable()
class OrderModel {
  String? completedByUid;
  String? completed; 
}
```

and i want to get the serialization name something like:

```
var updateFields = {
  OrderModel.completedByUid: authRepo.getUID(),
```

or

```
var updateFields = {
  order.completedByUid.properyName: authRepo.getUID(),
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally this would be a use for reflection but that might be overkill.

I think the design pattern you could use is a constant that you use to both set and read the values, like so:

`const String ORDER_MODEL_COMPLETED_BY_UID_PROPERTY = "completedByUid";`

This doesn't exactly guarantee a match if, for example, some existing data is present and may have a name mismatch.

For an answer based on reflection, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021327/how-do-i-get-all-fields-for-a-class-in-dart).