# How can I list all the classes in the Flutter 3 Widgets package?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am developing a [ClojureDart](https://github.com/Tensegritics/ClojureDart) library to wrap Flutter. Currently, I must do a straightforward hardcoded definition for each widget, to help [my library](https://github.com/kennytilton/flutter-mx) know how to handle it. eg, Is it stateful or not? What are the positional parameters, if any? etc

My goal is to write a program to dump out a JSON description of the classes/constructors of a given Flutter package, or at least the widgets package, so I can create all the definitions at once, and so my library users do not have to handcraft the definitions.

The Google and ChatGPT have led me to the mirror and analyzer packages, but the code suggested seems to not work well because of incompatibilities with Dart/Flutter 3. Or at least that is my takeaway -- I am not a Dart programmer, just learning enough to build my library.

(a) Is this even feasible? Do I need to scrape the Flutter web pages? (My fallback.)
(b) Are the mirror and or analyzer packages the way to go?
(c) Is there any example I can try that works with Dart 3?

Thx!

Comment: Maybe the answers in this discussion? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17021327/how-do-i-get-all-fields-for-a-class-in-dart